# JButton text having different CUSTOM fonts

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Now, I know, different font families can be achieved within a JButton text.
Like below

```
JButton button = new JButton("<html><font face=Arial>Hello </font><font face=Verdana>World</font></html>");
```

It looks like this. "Hello" with Arial and "World" with Verdana.

[image]

But, what if I want a word to have a font which I've created using `Font.createFont()` method. I thought, something like this, would have worked.

```
Font myFont = createMyFont();
JButton button = new JButton("<html><font face=MyFont>Hello </font>World</html>");
```

The significance of this question is that I am creating a multilingual software, which has two fonts in a single `JButton`.

So, I want my `JButton` to be like this:

[image]

But, it is like this:

[image]

Comment: The javadoc mentions to use `Font.registerFont()` after creating the font using `Font.createFont()`

Comment: Try register the font:

    `GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
         ge.registerFont(myFont);`

Comment: And then, from what name should I call it? With its file name?

Comment: @Akshat Should be the filename

Comment: Yes, it's working. But, I had to remove the '_' from its font file name "Devlys_010" and code it like <font face=\"Devlys 010\">ABC</font>.

Comment: I think, someone should make it as an answer. So, it can be helpful to others.

Comment: @Akshat you can answer by yourself and post relevant code that really works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register custom font with:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
ge.registerFont(myFont);
```

After, provide file name, something like:

```
      URL fontUrl;
        try {
            fontUrl = new URL("http://www.webpagepublicity.com/" +
                    "free-fonts/a/Airacobra%20Condensed.ttf"); // dummy font 

            Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontUrl.openStream());
            myFont = myFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN,20);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(myFont);


            button.setText("<html><font face='Airacobra Condensed'>Hello </font>World</html>");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The **filename** can be accquired on windows by rightclicking on the font file, selecting Properties -> Details and there it's the title. Example: FontAwesome Regular.

[image]